# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test33" (type string) at path "_id" for model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm self-studying web development by taking Colt Steele's udemy course and I jut hit the wall.. I don't know why it shows cast to ObjectId error in the below code.. I was trying to debug it but couldn't find the reason for this error msg. The only thing I found is that when I create/edit data by inputting/updating image url to just plain text without "http://", then it shows this error msg. Please help me.. I'm stuck in here for few days and still don'w understand..

Error Message

```
const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test33" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Yelpcamp"
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/doriyomi/Web Development/YELPCAMP/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4498:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/doriyomi/Web Development/YELPCAMP/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4592:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"test33"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'test33',
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CampGround = require('./models/main');
const methodOverride = require('method-override'); 
const engine = require('ejs-mate');

const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yelpcamp', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
db.then(()=> {
    console.log('connected to Mongo DB!');
})


//to use req.body. it must be needed.
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.engine('ejs', engine); //connect ejs-mate to ejs, then boilerplate layout can be used.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));

app.get('/main', async (req, res)=> {
    console.log("Basic route opened!!");
    const allData = await CampGround.find({});
    res.render('campground/main', {allData});
})
app.post('/main', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('New -> save() function opened');
    console.log(`title: ${req.body.campground.title}`);
    console.log(`image: ${req.body.campground.image}`);
    console.log(`location: ${req.body.campground.location}`);
    console.log(`price: ${req.body.campground.price}`);

 
    const newData = new CampGround(req.body.campground);
    await newData.save();

    res.redirect('/main');
})

app.get('/main/new', (req, res) => {
    // console.log('new page works in express');
    res.render('campground/new');
})


app.get('/main/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log('id page works');
    const {id} = req.params;
    const foundData = await CampGround.findById(id);
    res.render('campground/showbyid',{foundData});
})

app.put('/main/:id', async(req, res) => {
    // const {title, location} = req.body;
    // console.log(req.body.campground);
    await CampGround.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{...req.body.campground}, {new: true, useFindAndModify: false});
    
    res.redirect(`/main/${req.params.id}`);
})


app.get('/main/:id/edit', async(req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    const foundData = await CampGround.findById(id);
    console.log(foundData);
    res.render('campground/edit', {foundData});
})

app.delete('/main/:id', async(req, res) => {
    await CampGround.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, {useFindAndModify: false});
    res.redirect('/main');
})

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("Port open!!");
})
```

main.ejs //to show all the list

```
<% layout('./layout/boilerplate') %>

<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <h1>Campgrounds!!</h1>
    <% for(let a of allData.reverse()) { %>
        <div class="card w-75">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img src="<%=a.image%>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            <%=a.title%>
                        </h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                            <%=a.location%>
                        </h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <%=a.description%><br><br>
                                <a href="/main/<%=a._id%>" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

new.ejs // list creation part

```
<% layout('./layout/boilerplate') %>
<div class="row mt-5">
    <h1 class="text-center">New Data Creation</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/main" method="POST">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="titleid">Title: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="titleid" name="campground[title]" placeholder="Title here">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="locationid">Location: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="locationid" name="campground[location]" placeholder="Location here">
            </div>
            
            <label class="form-label" for="imgurlid">URL </label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="IMG URL here" id=imgurlid name="campground[image]">
            </div>

            <label class="form-label" for="priceid">Price </label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price here" id=priceid name="campground[price]">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="descid">Description: </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" id="descid" name="campground[description]" placeholder="Description here"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-success" >create</button>
            </div>

            <a href="/main/">Back to main</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your _id attribute in mongoose expecting id should should be 24 hex character/12 bytes long where in your case it is not . its "test33" which is not 12 bytes or 24 hex character, so you need to update that, that's why it failed to cast. Change that you would be good

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated "test33" to something like 6209ebcc31afb2535a673b08 and it doesn't show error msg now but what I don't understand is that why this data is being saved in _id attribute because the data "test33" is for img url, not for _id.  I think I am totally misunderstanding something:(

Comment: I guess somewhere you might referring the "test33" as _id or might be image url type in mangoose could be ObjectId type , so basically just check that image url in mangoose should be saved as text and imageurl should not point to _id somewhere in your code

Comment: I think so too. but I don't know where I referred the "test33" as _id. I looked through the entire code but couldn't find it..  could you help me to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

For me the issue was that I used the same structure url twice:

```js
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async (req,res) => {
    const campground = await CampGround.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('campgrounds/show', {campground});
})

app.get('/campgrounds/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('campgrounds/new');
})
```

Since "campgrounds/:id" comes first my get for "campgrounds/new" will result in allocating "new" as id.

Maybe this could be your cause as well? Or if it helps anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I solve it by doing this:

```
router.get("/logout", function (req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.flash("success", "Goodbye");
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
  });
});
```

The docs also shows it,
you can check it out in the link below:
https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/logout/

I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, I solved it by modifying the following lines.

Take as an example:

```js
app.get('/main/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log('id page works');
    const {id} = req.params;
    const foundData = await CampGround.findById(id);
    res.render('campground/showbyid',{foundData});
});
```

In my code it would be:

```js
app.get('/main/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log('id page works');
    const id = req.params.id;
    const foundData = await CampGround.findOne({_id: id});
    res.render('campground/showbyid',{foundData});
});
```

I hope to be of help, at least for you to try another option.